# How to enable Unicode encoding using JPA EclipseLink?

Tags: java, jpa, unicode, eclipselink, sybase

I am using JPA EclipseLink in my project and the DB is Sybase. When i am trying to persist an user entity which have name with characters other than english, for ex `'ΙΩΑΝΝΗΣ'` the save operation is getting failed and message says

> "Internal Exception: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Data
>   exception - string data right truncated".

When i searched stack overflow for answers i got few answers about how to do it using Hibernate, but couldnt find using JPA.
My question is can we set any property in `persistence.xml` or can we set it on entity level to enable Unicode encoding?

If so how, please help me with resolving this issue. Many thanks.

Progress- I have added following in persistance.xml file.But still the issue isnt resolved.

`<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.property.sendStringParametersAsUnicode" value="true"/>`

Comment: I have added "<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.property.sendStringParametersAsUnicode" value="true"/>" in persistance.xml file.But still the issue isnt resolved.

Comment: One needs to realize that `VARCHAR(20)` means 20 bytes. With ~3 bytes UTF-8 for 7 letters already 1 byte is truncated. Be generous and quadruple all sizes.

Comment: @JoopEggen...Thanks a lot. After increasing the size it works.